# Error converting a column from object to float in Python

Tags: python, pandas

After getting data from Yahoo of Bitcoin using Pandas I try to create a simple trading strategy: I want to buy when the Close is > Mean of the last 50 days and sell when that expression is false.

In order to simulate this I create different columns:

a)  Column MA50: Which shows the Mean of the last 50 Closes.

b)  Column Signal: Which shows 1 when the Close > Mean. Otherwise 0.

c)  Column Close1: Which shows the close of tomorrow (necessary for the calculations of the daily profit/loss)

d)  Column Profit: Shows the daily profit / loss produced by the strategy.

In order to calculate the Profit column I simply subtract the Close1 – Close when Signal value is equal to 1. If the expression is false the Profit is 0. 
As you can see here, all the values are numerical, however when I get the result of Profit I see that it has been created as an object and not as a numerical value.

As I need the column Profit as a numerical value I have tried to convert the column using this function `pd.to_numeric()` but unfortunately it didn't work. I also tried to convert the Profit column using `df['Profit'] = df['Profit'].astype(float)`. But it din't work either.

Below you can see the entire code that I’m using and pointing at where the error is produced:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as dr
from datetime import date

# Create DataFrame and create the Moving Average (mean) of last 50 closes
fb = dr.data.get_data_yahoo('btc-usd',start='23-01-2017',end=date.today())
fb['MA50'] = fb['Close'].rolling(50).mean()
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 5400)

# Add a new column "Signal". When the close > MA50 Signal is 1 if not Singal is 0.
fb['Signal'] = [1 if (fb.loc[ei, 'Close']>fb.loc[ei, 'MA50']).all() else 0 for ei in fb.index]

#Add a new column "Profit", for any rows, if Signal=1, the profit is calculated as the close price of tomorrow - the close price of today. If not the profit is 0.
fb['Close1'] = fb['Close'].shift(-1)
fb['Profit'] = [(fb.loc[ei, 'Close1'] - fb.loc[ei, 'Close']) if (fb.loc[ei, 'Signal']==1).all() else 0 for ei in fb.index] #---> The error is produced in this line of code for this formula: (fb.loc[ei, 'Close1'] - fb.loc[ei, 'Close']).
```

For an unknown reason if I do `fb.info()` I see that the values of the Profit column have been created as an object and not as a `float64`.

I also can see that in some rows the result of Profit is not numerical. (See attachment).

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQ8iw.png)
[image]

My objective is to plot the Profit column in a chart using `fb['Profit'].plot()`. The issue is that the Profit column is not numerical and for that reason when I try it I get the next message:

```
TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot
```

I apologize in advance for the long letter. I have tried to make it shorter before but I was not able to explain myself correctly. Any help would be more than welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Can you paste some sample data? I am getting `ImmediateDeprecationError: 
Yahoo Actions has been immediately deprecated due to large breaks in the API without the
introduction of a stable replacement. Pull Requests to re-enable these data
connectors are welcome.`

Comment: What are you trying to do here? The expression `2>1` will always be true?

Comment: Describe what you want to do, not why your code is not working, see [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Exactly Erfan, in this example the expression 2 > 1 will always be true. In this case the problem is not the expression but the result. As you can see the result is shown as an object instead as a float64. For clarification I used 2 > 1 but it could be replaced to (df.loc[ei,'Close'] > df.loc[ei,'Open']) or any other expression. My problem is with the result. My final objective is to be able to plot X thru df['X'].plot(). Thanks!

Comment: Thank you Vivek. I appreciate your help guys. I tried to paste it but unfortunately the data format is not easy to read. In order to get Yahoo data is necessary to install Pandas data_reader. Other choice is to download it from the BTC-USD website: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BTC-USD/history?p=BTC-USD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put list into X, containing numbers and strings. This can't be converted to numerical.

If you want for instance, as you wrote in the comments above, X be the Close value if it is above Open or 0 otherwise, then do the following:

```
df['X'] = df.Close.where(df.Close > df.Open, 0)
```

### UPDATE based on your new explanation:

```
import numpy as np
# Add a new column "Signal". When the close > MA50 Signal is 1 if not Singal is 0.
fb['Signal'] = np.where(fb.Close > fb.MA50, 1, 0)

#Add a new column "Profit", for any rows, if Signal=1, the profit is calculated as the close price of tomorrow - the close price of today. If not the profit is 0.
fb['Close1'] = fb['Close'].shift(-1)
fb['Profit'] = np.where(fb.Signal == 1, fb.Close1 - fb.Close, 0)
```

Don't use your list comprehension constructs, they are wrong and introduce text data which can't be converted to numeric.

Comment: Thank you Stef! I appreciate the help. I can see that the X is now shown as a float64. However, the problem with your code is that the X result is always the same in each row (in this case 314.890015). If you remove the "[0]" of your first line of code you will see that the X result is shown correctly in each row (notice that is always different). The problem is that the result is shown as an object instead as a float64. So, as it is not a numeric value I can't use the X for example to plot it using df['X'].plot()

Comment: @Martingale I'm afraid I can't help you unless you explain what do you want to put into column X. Right now your X is at first identical with Close, but later it contains some strange text (look for instance at `df.iloc[87]['X']`.

Comment: @Martingale I made a guess based on one of your comments above and updated my answer: is it that what you intended to do?

Comment: First of all thank you Stef. I have edited the question being much more specific. It seems that for some reason the results of the Profit Column (former X) sometimes are not numerical (thank you for pointing me to that direction). What I finally need to do is to convert the entire column to numerical to solve the problem.

Comment: You deserve the sky Stef !! Your last answer solved it perfectly. THANK YOU SO MUCH.